# HTML, CSS, JS Minification

Tags: javascript, html, css, minify

Is there any minifier/minifier suite that minifes HTML, JavaScript and CSS together? Specifically, it should:

1. Follow links from the HTML and minify JavaScript and CSS.
2. Remove JavaScript functions, and CSS styles that are not used anywhere.
3. Minify JavaScript function names, CSS class names and apply these changes to the HTML.
4. Output a single HTML file with JS and CSS inline.

I have found a lot of tools for minifying HTML, or JS, or CSS, but none for doing the things mentioned above.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @bjb568: Thank you. I was really confused about what the down-votes were for. Point Taken.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) with next tasks: [jshint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint), [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) and [cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin).